# Extjs : Show data on Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Although I am getting output in the response

> Response

```
{
    "result": [{
        "date": "",
        "emailID": "",
        "name": ""
    }, {
        "date": "2007-04-04T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "fgffg",
        "name": "cvbgfv"
    }, {
        "date": "2009-07-15T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "hfgh",
        "name": "gjhgh"
    }, {
        "date": "2009-10-07T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "gdfd",
        "name": "dfgdf"
    }, {
        "date": "2010-02-10T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "vcvc",
        "name": "bvcb"
    }, {
        "date": "2011-04-08T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "dfgfdgd",
        "name": "fvdf"
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-18T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "dgffdgfd",
        "name": "rgffdg"
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-07T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "dsfsdfsd",
        "name": "sdfdsfdsf"
    }, { ... // skipped some lines
        "date": "2019-04-08T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "vcvbc",
        "name": "dg"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-05T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "dgfd",
        "name": "dfgfdg"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-21T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "dgfd",
        "name": "dfgfdg"
    }, {
        "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "fgf",
        "name": "vfdvf"
    }, {
        "date": "2020-01-14T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "nbvb",
        "name": "fgf"
    }, {
        "date": "2020-04-14T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "fdgdf",
        "name": "dgdf"
    }, {
        "date": "2020-06-09T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "sfdds",
        "name": "dsfsd"
    }, {
        "date": "2020-09-23T00:00:00",
        "emailID": "fdfgf",
        "name": "vcxv"
    }],
    "success": true,
    "totalcount": 84
}
```

---

> Here is my `store` & `grid`

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     autoLoad: true,
     fields: [{
         name: 'date',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'emailID',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'name',
         type: 'string'
     }],
     pageSize: 10, // items per page
     id: 'date',
     proxy: {
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'rest/helloworld/submit',
         noCache: false,
         type: 'ajax',
         root: 'result',
         totalProperty: 'totalcount'
     }
 });

 // specify segment of data you want to load using params
 store.load({
     params: {
         start: 0,
         limit: 10
     }
 });

 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
     title: 'Result',
     store: store,
     columns: [{
         header: 'Name',
         dataIndex: 'name'
     }, {
         header: 'Email',
         dataIndex: 'emailID',
         flex: 1
     }, {
         header: 'Date',
         dataIndex: 'date'
     }],
     width: 400,

     dockedItems: [{
         xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
         store: store,
         dock: 'bottom',
         displayInfo: true
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```

---

But it is not visible on the `grid`.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `reader`:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'result',
    totalProperty: 'totalcount'
}
```

Your example working: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l3u